# I am trying to use less but when i installed angular cli i accepted it as CSS in comand line. now i am getting less error

Tags: angular, less

I have installed angular cli and when installing it asked me to install what kind of ccs flavour you want to install i entered CSS and it got installed but when trying to use less i am getting errors. can some one please help me how to change it to less

Comment: I have often done something similar. A handy trick.... use the CLI to create another demo project, and this time choose `less` as the style option. You can then search for `style` in the `angular.json`, and copy over the changes. Also search for anything with `less`, and make the appropriate changes

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify your `angular.json` file. Check out the docs here: https://angular.io/guide/workspace-config#additional-build-and-test-options.

Answer (score 0):

changes needs to do in `package.json`.

```
"schematics": {
            "@schematics/angular:component": {
              "style": "less"
            }
          },
```

Then in `architect` property change this

```
"styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
```

to

```
"styles": [
              "src/styles.less"
            ],
```

Then in `test` property do same change.

Let me know if you have any doubt.